# Drag Manager in Flex - how to get rid of the red cross?

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I'm making a Matching Game, where I have some pictures on my left side and they can be dragged and dropped onto matching pictures on my right. I'm using the Drag Manager, which works great, but I have one problem. When dragging an object, I can see a small icon of a red cross, if the picture can not be dropped at this place (and it can't be dropped, if it doesn't match). Of course, in case of the game, I don't want the user to know instantly where he can drop the picture... Is there any way to get rid of this indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was wrong before. You need to accept the drag operation on dragEnter event handler if you want the "red cross" to disappear. Event if you try to display a different feedback, without accepting the drag operation the cross (meaning no operation) will still appear. So leave the check for the matching out of dragEnter handler and put in dragDrop event handler, and accept the drag for all your images.

Method hideDropFeedback is defined in the list components (List, DataGrid etc.), and it hides a certain line that appears when dragging items in those controls. This one doesn't matter in your particular case.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work... but I checked in Adobe livedocs and they say this statement would be to SHOW that indicator. and i want to HIDE it. i found something like this though: event.currentTarget.hideDropFeedback(event); just that this one doesn't seem to work either.. when I open my app in Firefox and start dragging, I get an err :/

Comment: Modified my answer, as it didn't correctly deal with the problem. This one, however, is tested.